# phpdoc: What's the proper way to document a constant

Tags: php, phpdoc

Is there a proper way to document a constant defined using `define()`? @var doesn't really make sense. The only thing I can think of is to omit the tag, and just write the description in the PHPdoc comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

phpDocumentor does not recognize or utilize a @const tag.  phpDocumentor recognizes a constant when it sees the "define" keyword in the code.  Its output templates will show all constants in the output documentation, listed as constants.  The only thing needed in the constant's docblock is a description, although many other "standard" tags are allowed if you feel like you need them [1].

[1] -- http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_elements.pkg.html#procedural.define

Answer (score 1):

Use `@const`.

```
/**
  * @const FOO Bar
  */
define('FOO', 'Bar');
```

[Documentation](http://www.phpdoc.de/kongress/constant.html) (Sorry, the only docs I can find are in German.)

Comment: I did come across that, however, I can't find mention of it anywhere else and NetBeans doesn't show it the auto-complete hints.

Answer (score 1):

You actually want to use `@type`, see the [Github PHP Documentation](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/blob/develop/docs/PSR.md#721-type).

Answer (score 0):

My version of phpDocumentor (2.9.0) actually shows text if you don't use any tag at all and write the text directly. Though, it's treated like a function/method header: first line is a summary and everything else is the description.

```
/** 
 * The meaning of life.
 */
const MYSTERY = 42;
```

Furthermore, I can confirm that `@const` and `@type` "work" in that the text appears in a sidebar under "Tags" – rather than directly underneath the constant in the main column.