# phpDoc way to list which outside constants a class uses?

Tags: php, documentation, phpdoc

Is there a best practice way of documenting which outside constants are used by a PHP class?

For example, I have a class that logs data to a text file.  This class creates a file and puts it into a directory.  The path to this directory is the constant APP_LOG_PATH.  How should I document my code, so that someone can quickly look at the PHP class and know APP_LOG_PATH needs to be defined somewhere in the calling code.  Something like:

```
/**
* Write to file
*
* @depends_on APP_LOG_PATH
* @param string The file name
* @param string The content to write
*/
static public function write_to_file($filename, $content){
    file_put_contents(APP_LOG_PATH . $filename, $content);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might consider using a [@uses](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/default/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.uses.pkg.html) tag for it. From the description:

> The @uses tag may be used to document any element (global variable, include, page, class, function, define, method, variable)

It goes on to say that it will attempt to create a backlink on the item being used, so the documentation can show what functions/methods will be using it.

Comment: Using the "uses APP_LOG_PATH" in that function's docblock is indeed a great option.  That function's docblock will show the "uses APP_LOG_PATH" on its doc page, allowing you to link back to that constant.  Then, the constant's doc page will show "usedby write_to_file()", which is a link back to the function itself.  Using uses like this for all functions that use your constant will result (*automatically* via usedby tags) in your constant's doc page showing you all the functions that rely on that constant.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use dependency injection, which then you could document it on your injection function / parameter. Another way would be to document the constant on the define's docblock, which is a solution referenced in [phpdoc: What's the proper way to document a constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995753/phpdoc-whats-the-proper-way-to-document-a-constant)